# Angular : Set host config depends on domain

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i really don't know how to do it

i have this code on my angular controller :

```
vm.orderData = [];
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://footest.com/api/v1/order'
    }).success(function(data, status){
      vm.orderData = data.data;
    }).error(function(data, status){
      alert("error");
    });
```

as you know `footest.com` is just the dummy localhost.
and i want the url auto replace when i visit my real host

example:

when i'm try my code on `foo.com` the code will change to

```
vm.orderData = [];
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://foo.com/api/v1/order'
    }).success(function(data, status){
      vm.orderData = data.data;
    }).error(function(data, status){
      alert("error");
    });
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: just use this: '/api/v1/order' in url parameter it should work

Comment: You have some backend right? Like a node server or something that renders the initial page? What you can do is have a `config.json` on the server and set api urls based on production environment. Then when you render the home page or first route. Just set those config params to the window object doing something like `window.config`. You do this from the backend. Now in your angular app would always have access to those config params.